# Sculpt deformation fix

Tags: sculpting

I am at my very first sculpting attemppt and having some deformations, as to be seen in the picture. If anyone can explain how this comes up, how to get rid of it and how to avoid it in the first place, I would be really thankful!

[image]

Comment: That looks like unconnected geometry - either another mesh of the same object or another object popping up after sculpted surface is moved down or errors in geometry of the sculpted mesh like non-manifold geometry sitting inside. All of these might be hidden in Edit mode but visible when sculpting

Comment: But there is nothing else, no doubles, nothing. The base mesh is a very simply extruded cylinder.